# How can Doxygen handle includes within enum declarations

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor, doxygen

We do have several C-projects targeting resource-constrained systems, which rely heavily on enums defined through preprocessor macros in special resource files. These files get included within the enum definition.

This concept is used to have the user of our API to "be only allowed" to edit the resource definition file, but not needing to touch the header file where these enums are actually defined. Additionally it allows to generate strings for these events, too.

### Example for a resource file

```c
DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE(EVENT_ALERT)
DEF_OTHER_EVENT_TYPE(EVENT_OTHER_ALERT)
DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE(EVENT_FLASH)
DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE(EVENT_BEEP)
```

### Example for the associated enum definition

```c
enum some_event_e
{
  #define DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE(name) name,
  #define DEF_SOME_OTHER_EVENT_TYPE(name)
  #include "resource_definitions.g"
  #undef DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE
  #undef DEF_SOME_OTHER_EVENT_TYPE 
  SOME_EVENT_COUNT
};

enum some_other_event_e
{
  #define DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE(name) name,
  #define DEF_SOME_OTHER_EVENT_TYPE(name)
  #include "resource_definitions.g"
  #undef DEF_SOME_EVENT_TYPE
  #undef DEF_SOME_OTHER_EVENT_TYPE 
  SOME_OTHER_EVENT_COUNT
};
```

When trying to document the enumerators, doxygen seems to not properly expand these macros and include the resource definition file.

Suppose we have the following **documentation block**:

```c
/*! 
  @enum some_event_e
  @brief Some event identifiers
*/

/*!
  @var some_event_e::EVENT_ALERT
  @brief alert event
*/

/*!
  @var some_event_e::SOME_EVENT_COUNT
  @brief Total number of some events
*/
```

**Doxygen will properly document `SOME_EVENT_COUNT`, but will throw a warnign for `EVENT_ALERT`.**

```
warning: documented symbol 'some_event_e::EVENT_ALERT' was not declared or defined.
```

`ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` and `MACRO_EXPANSION` are both set to `YES` in `Doxyfile` and I've added `*.g` (the file-extension used for resource definitions) to the `INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS` and did add it to `EXTENSION_MAPPING` via `g=C`. I'm using doxygen version 1.8.16.

**Is there a way to be able to document enum values declared in this manner?** In some cases it is really useful to use this sort of macro-magic to define enums, so it would be immensely helpful if it was possible to document these with doxygen.

Comment: Does the `resource_definitions.g` end with empty line? I recall that there was some issues with X-macros and doxygen if there wasn't empty line at the end of file. But this was years ago, and may not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ?

Comment: @albert I edited the question to contain the Doxygen version.

Comment: @user694733 Our compiler issues warning if there is no empty line before the end of the file, so this can't be the issue.

Comment: It may be unhappy about /multiply/ including the same G file? Given the first one seems to work and the second does not.

Comment: @GemTaylor The first one doesn't work either. These files of course do not have any include guards.

Comment: Ok, sorry, me reading too fast. I guess the documentation block is a separate file? It is a pain, but you might be forced to use the compiler preprocessor to do the expansion. There is a useful option to keep comments if you also rely on inline documentation: `gcc -E -CC`

Comment: @GemTaylor Looking at it again, the multiple inclusion indeed seems to be the issue at the core; I didn't really test the minimal example I posted, so I felt that was not the cause. When I looked at the preprocessor output, I saw several instances of #include resource_definitions.g: already included! skipping... which lead me to suggest that this is the issue I'm having. I also stumbled upon an [open issue in the doxygen issue tracker](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6856).